# how to label points in a 3d plot? Matplotlib | Mpl_toolkit

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, scatter-plot

python newbie here, I have searched the forums for an answer but I don't seem to find a definite solution.

My matrix looks as follows:

```
Country | Agri   | Manu | Serv | 
AFG     | 0.7    | 0.1  |  0.3 |
ALB     | 0.2    | 0.5  |  0.4 |
BEL     | 0.1    | 0.8  |  0.1 |
```

I would like to label each data point by Country (Col. 0).  How can I do this?

My code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
ax=fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')

ax.scatter(orig_df['Agri'],
        orig_df['Manu'],
         orig_df['Serv'],
        marker='o',
        color='b',
        alpha=0.7,
        s = 124)

ax.set_title('Three Sector Economy')
ax.set_xlabel('Agriculture')
ax.set_xlim([0,1])
ax.set_ylabel('Manufacturing')
ax.set_ylim([0,1])
ax.set_zlabel('Services')
ax.set_zlim([0,1])

plt.show()
```

My output:
[3D pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnqgk.png)

Comment: use the `label` option in your plot function, then call `plt.legend()`

Comment: or have a look at `annotate` for fancier options